# FPV stream on a PC with SkyDroid - how to reduce lag?

Tags: video-signal, analog-fpv-system

I have connected my SkyDroid receiver to a Windows 10 laptop and opened the corresponding video capture device with VLC:

[image]

As you can see, it works pretty well, but there's a lag of 0.5..1 second, which is too much even for comfortable navigation in the OSD menu.

Are there any tips on how to reduce the lag? Perhaps there are settings in VLC that could help, or custom device drivers?

Comment: This system is going to likely have unflyably high latency just due to the hardware. USB is a heavy stack that focuses on speed, not latency; unfortunately that cannot be changed. You may be able to stay in the air, but it will not be good quality

Comment: @BrydonGibson I don't plan to fly like that. I want to use my PC's screen to navigate the menu while configuring the craft on my workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reduce latency to nothing by using the CAMERA windows native app instead of VLC (issues with VLC). You just have to change the default webcam to the "USB2 PC Camera" in the parameters of this apps:
[image]

Like you I use the Skydroid Diversity 5.8 Dual receiver to fly indoor with my PC and that works very well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try next time.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works much better than VLC. I have added a picture showing where exactly the video source is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the lag to almost nothing by changing the parameters when starting the stream. The setting you're concerned with is located in the "SHOW MORE OPTIONS" menu dialog. Just reduce the "CACHING" value to 0 milliseconds and then begin the stream. Test the lag to see if it's been reduced. I hope this helps!

Comment: Setting caching to 0 ms pretty much ruins the video, but a 200 ms value worked fine with total delay of less than 0.5s.